# C++, Qt Putting data into Mysql database: through PHP script OR directly from the program

Tags: php, c++, mysql, performance, qt

I'm making a program which will be always gathering some data and putting them into  a MySQL database, now i have two way to accomplish that and i wanted to knwo which one is better:

1- As i'm using Qt i can use QtSql module to connect directly to the DB and insert data

2- I can aslo write a PHP script using GET or POST varibles to insert data into the DB and just call the URL from my program with the suitable data.

I'm most worried about performance, as there will a lot of insertion all the time (about 100inserts / second). But the data size of each insertion is not that big, it will not exceed 10 charcaters.

I would point out that the Web server(where the php script will be stored), the DB server and the Server where the program will be running are all on the same local network

Comment: is program and db on the same server?

Comment: no, but there are on the same local network, in fact the Web server, the DB server and the Server where the program will be running are all on the same local network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your environment. Is the MySQL DB running on your local PC? Then, QtSql should be perfectly fine.

If the DB is publicly accessible (eg. via the internet), then this would be a bad idea. You generally should avoid exposing MySQL DB servers directly to public network and instead provide access e.g. via locked-down interfaces such as your PHP one.

edit: From a pure performance-centric point of view, the QtSql solution should definitely be faster (though the only way to be sure is to benchmark it!). The PHP solution would have at least the following elements that generate overhead:

- Data transfer over a network socket
- Startup of the PHP interpreter (is it still the case that PHP is started once for each request? If so, this is going to be significant.)

Comment: Okay, here you're talking about security, but what about the performance will it be the same for the two case I mentioned ?

Comment: I added something about that to my answer.

Comment: Ok, i see, i think i'll use QtSQL module for the moment as they are all on the same LAN, if ever the program became obliged to reach the DB over internet for some reason, i'll use the PHP solution because security. Thanks!